# Debugging dynamic Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This is a real noob question, but i'm fairly new to developing C# in combination with ASP.NET and JS. I have a situation where I have javascript stored in a database and which is rendered dynamically on a page.

Because of the size of the page it is difficult to find the scripts client side and therefore it is hard to debug the javascript. I now change the scripts in the DB and add alerts to display my debugging results, is there an easier way to set some sort of breakpoint in my script?

Anil Shabitsomin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not realy sure what you are looking for but it is possible to add a

```
debugger;
```

statement to your Javascript code.
All browsers will break on it and you are able to debug your script.

Grt,
Patrick

Comment: +1... after years and years of working with javascript in browsers, I only *now* just discover this!!

Comment: :) I noticed before that is this apparently one of the best hidden features of Javascript.